# RubyOnRails3 - event_calendar

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I use event_calendar gem and it works probably for me, but I face problem of how to change color of events by type, I mean how to make for example personal events like birthday or trip colored with blue and work events like meetings colored with red etc..
Can this be done by css or code? I hope you can help me with this -- Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

http://dev.elevationblog.com/2009/07/23/event-calendar-rails-plugin/

After loading almost all the comments I found the answer to that question.

just override the color method in your event model.

```
def color
# color logic based on event type
# or maybe associated calendar?, ie
# self.calendar.color
   if self.type = correct_type 
      return "#3399BB" #any html acceptable color  
   end
end
```

answered by jeff

do your logic then return the color you want to used

Answer (score 0):

I did things a little differently for more flexibility based on info I found on this site.

**Output**

```
  <div class="btn-group event_color" data-toggle="buttons-radio">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" value="#00a651">Active</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" value="#ecef0b">Pending</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" value="#ef0b0b">On Hold</button>
    <%=f.hidden_field :color %>
    <%=f.hidden_field :event_status %>
  </div>
```

**JS**

```
   $(".event_color .btn").click(function() {
   // whenever a button is clicked, set the hidden helper
   $('#event_color').val($(this).val());
   }); 

   $(".event_color .btn").click(function() {
   // whenever a button is clicked, set the hidden helper
   $("#event_event_status").val($(this).text());
   });
```